# How do I print numbers starting from 0 to a given input using recursion (details in post)?

Tags: python, recursion

More detail: I am given a max number and have to print from 0 to that number, with some other info between each number.

What I mean is a function like this:

```
>>>print_num(2,4)
```

this would print the following output:

```
0    
4    
1    
4   
2
```

Basically given the first input, print 0 and then the second input until you reach the max. I have to do this with just recursion in python.

What I have:

```
def print_num(num, info):
    if num == 0:
        print(num)
    else:
        print(num)
        print(info)
        print_num(num-1,info)
```

Output:

```
2
4
1
4
0
```

The problem is this prints from the number to 0, and not from 0 to the number. Can someone help me reverse the order? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: A more fun way to do this: write a recursive `interleave(iterable, value)` generator, then your main function is just `for n in interleave(range(num), info)): print(n)`. And then you can replace `range` with another recursive generator function, as an added exercise. Then replace the `for` loop with yet another recursive function. Almost certainly not what your teacher/book/whatever is expecting, but you’d probably learn a lot by trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `print_num` before your prints, to reverse the print order

```
def print_num(num, info):
    if num == 0:
        print(num)
    else:
        print_num(num-1,info)
        print(info)
        print(num)


print_num(2, 4)
```

output:

```
0
4
1
4
2
```

You could simplify it:

```
def print_num(num, info):
    if num > 0:
        print_num(num-1,info)
        print(info)
    print(num)
```

Comment: @ScottHunter why not? Did you try it?

Comment: You also reversed the order of the "prints".

Comment: @ScottHunter the question is what makes the order `0` -> `1` -> `2` instead of `2` -> `1` -> `0`, and the answer is *"calling `print_num` before printing... `num`"*

Comment: @ScottHunter This is all that’s needed is kind of the whole point—not only that, it’s just a specific instance of a general problem with recursion that can always be solved this way (e.g., when the OP later needs to write pre-order, in-order, and post-order tree traversals, remembering this answer will tell them how to solve that one too).